# How to handle Slim API JWT Authentication

Tags: php, jwt, slim

I already generated a token from my api login using this code:

```
    if ($isCorrect == 1) {
        $key = "example_key";
        $token = array(
            "iss" => "http://mywebsite.com",
            "iat" => 1356999524,
            "nbf" => 1357000000,
            'data' => [                  
                'userName' => $UserName,
            ]
        );

        $jwt = JWT::encode($token, $key);
        $decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $key, array('HS256'));

        $unencodedArray = ['jwt' => $jwt];
        echo json_encode($unencodedArray);
    }
```

So I have a token now, how can I use the token to other api? What I mean is, i dont want anybody to perform this api without logging in.

This is my sample API method:

```
$app->get('/api/user/{UserId}', function($request){ 
//Select query here
});
```

This is the library i used: https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: "i dont want anybody to perform this api without logging in." I don't understand what you mean. Getting a JWT is going through the process of logging in. Are you trying to use multiple authentication layers? Or asking about how to verify the user is who they say they are and thus can safely be given a JWT that identifies them (that question would be *very* broad)?

Comment: What I mean is that my API can access by anyone, so if i have a delete method, anyone can perform this without logging in/ generating JWT.

Comment: You could use JWT authentication middleware: https://github.com/tuupola/slim-jwt-auth

Comment: Thank you very much sir. It works.

Answer (score 0):

You Just need to add a middleware  method for your API 
that will check the validation of the JWT token with that user name
Then pass the request to the API

`

```
 $app->add( function ( $Req ,$Res ,$next ){
       //get token,username from the user 
    $token= $Req->getParsedBodyParam('token');
    $user_name=$Req->getParsedBodyParam('username');
    //check for empty of any of them
    if(empty ($token)|| empty($user_name)  ){
    $message=array("success"=>false,'message'=>'Some data is empty');
    return $Res->withStatus(401)
               -> withJson($message);
    }
    else{ 

    //Validation test for the taken for this user name 
                $decoded_token = $this->JWT::decode($token, 'YourSecret key', array('HS256'));
                if( isset($decoded_token->data->userName) && $decoded_token->data->userName == $user_Name ){
               $message=array('message'=>'the token is valid');
//pass through the next API 
                 $Res=$next($Req,$Res->withJson($message));
               return $Res;
                }
                else{
    $message=array("sccess"=>false,"message"=>"Token Validation Error",'code'=>201);
    return $Res->withStatus(401)
            ->withJson($message);
                }
    }
    });
    `
```